# syntax error unexpected character after line continuation character При запуске Pyton файлов в консоли

Tags: python-3.x

```
dist = 0    #Расстояние которое нужно проехать
speed = 0   #Средняя Скорость авто (км/ч)
dist = int (input ("Расстояние, которое нужно проехать:"))
speed = int(input("Планируемая средняя скорость:"))
time = dist * 60 / speed
print ("Будет затрачено", time, " минут")
```

Не думаю что ошибка в тексте, но все равно скинул.И такая ошибка в последних работах.Только начинаю изучать pyton.Может я делаю что то глупое?Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какой командой Вы запускаете файл?

Comment: Я перетаскиваю файл в командную строку и нажимаю Enter

Comment: Правильно `python path/to/file.py` (либо `python3`).

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно в консоли указать путь к файлу. Я это сделал, выдает ту жы самую ошибку

Comment: @bezobrazie, вы запускаете в cmd консоль python, потом туда перетаскиваете файл и нажимаете enter? Нужно просто запустить cmd, в ней прописать python и путь к файлу, но заранее консоль python не запускать.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно понять. как ты запускаешь это через консоль. 
Открой консоль, и одной строчкой пропиши там `"путь к питону" "путь к файлу"`
Сами полные пути можно увидеть в свойства, безопасность, верхняя строчка. Так-то код весь верный